# Delete Chars in Python

Tags: python

does anybody know how to delete all characters behind a specific character??

like this:

```
http://google.com/translate_t
```

into

```
http://google.com
```

Comment: This isn't *really* deleting -- Python can't update a string.  This is extracting a substring up to a given position.  You might want to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 6):

if you're asking about an abstract string and not url you could go with:

```
>>> astring ="http://google.com/translate_t"
>>> astring.rpartition('/')[0]
http://google.com
```

Comment: `string` is a builtin module in Python therefore it is bad to use it as a  variable name.

Comment: @jfs: it's a standard library module. it may or may not clash with certain variable names.

Comment: Note the rpartition method only exists in Python 2.5+, for earlier versions you'd need to use rsplit('/', 1).

Comment: @Carl Meyer actually `rsplit("/", 1)[0]`

Answer (score 5):

For urls, using [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> parts = urlparse.urlsplit('http://google.com/path/to/resource?query=spam#anchor')
>>> parts
('http', 'google.com', '/path/to/resource', 'query=spam', 'anchor')
>>> urlparse.urlunsplit((parts[0], parts[1], '', '', ''))
'http://google.com'
```

For arbitrary strings, using [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'\b/\b', 'http://google.com/path/to/resource', 1)
['http://google.com', 'path/to/resource']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str="http://google.com/translate_t"
shortened=str[0:str.rfind("/")]
```

Should do it. str[a:b] returns a substring in python. And rfind is used to find the index of a character sequence, starting at the end of the string.

Comment: Also, if there is no "/" in the string, this returns the initial string shortened by one character.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the position of the character then you can use the slice syntax to to create a new string:

```
In [2]: s1 = "abc123"
In [3]: s2 = s1[:3]
In [4]: print s2
abc
```

To find the position you can use the `find()` or `index()` methods of strings.
The `split()` and `partition()` methods may be useful, too.
Those methods are documented in the [Python docs for sequences](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange).

To remove a part of a string is imposible because strings are immutable.

If you want to process URLs then you should definitely use the [urlparse library](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html). It lets you split an URL into its parts. If you just want remove a part of the file path then you will have to do that still by yourself.