# python how to delete strings after a keyword

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete Chars in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549130/delete-chars-in-python)

I want to know how to delete strings after a keyword in python

I will get lines in a txt file

What method could I use to do this.

For example:

"I have a book to read."

I want to delete all words after "book".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove everything after the first "book" including "book" itself:

```
s = "I have a book to read."
print(s.partition("book")[0])
```

To preserve the word "book":

```
print(''.join(s.partition("book")[:2]))
```

Both work whether "book" present in the string or not.

Comment: keyword should be included in the result string.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

mystr = "I have a book to read."
keyword = 'book'

**Method 1**:

```
def foo(mystr, keyword):
    try:
        i = mystr.index(keyword)
        return mystr[:i+len(keyword)]
    except ValueError:
        return mystr
```

**Method 2**:

```
def foo(mystr, keyword):
    i = mystr.find(keyword)
    if i >= 0:
        return mystr[:i+len(keyword)]
    else:
        return mystr
```

**Method 3**:

```
def foo(mystr, keyword):
    return ''.join(mystr.partition(keyword)[:2])
```

Comment: keyword should be included in the result string.

Comment: @MuMind: you're right. My solutions have been edited

Comment: If `keyword` is a variable, you might also want to use `len(keyword)` instead of `4`

Comment: gah! you're right. I guess I'm just tired from my day

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Why? I would say it's actually more pythonic to use the bare except, especially in this case, as only `index` will throw any exception.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: [Idioms and Anti-Idioms in Python](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/doanddont.html#except)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: You're right. I misremembered PEP8. [It clearly states to avoid the bare except](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations). Answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do this is with `re.sub`.  (Output is shown interleaved with code.)

```
txt = 'I have a book to read'; key='book'
str = re.sub(key+'.*', key, txt)
str
'I have a book'
txt = 'I have a look to read'; key='book'
str = re.sub(key+'.*', key, txt)
str
'I have a look to read'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the stirng method find() which return the index of the first letter of the world:

```
str = "i have a book to read"
print str[:str.find("book") + len("book")]
```

This will work only because "book" exists in the string "i have a book to read". If this were not the case, this solution would not work as expected

Comment: wouldn't work if `'book'` is not in the string. In that case, `find` returns `-1` and you end up returning the first 3 characters of the input string

Answer (score 0):

Regex would be good for this:

```
import re
m = re.match('(.*book)', line)
if m:
    line = m.group(1)
```

or

```
line = re.sub('book.*', 'book', line)
```

Comment: Um... guess somebody just really hates regexes? Or likes downvoting...